# Jwebunit Exception invoking setOuterHTML

Tags: java, jwebunit

i am trying to place text in a textbox using jwebunit and i keep getting a "Exception invoking setOuterHTML" error. this is the code that i think is causing the issue

```
tester.setTextField("ctl00$ctl00$ContentMain$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucCreateEditCustomer$ucBillingAddressForm$tbFirstName", Database1[0][0]);
```

because the exception is caused by

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Did not find form element with name  
["ctl00$ctl00$ContentMain$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucCreateEditCustomer$ucBillingAddressForm$tbFirstName"].
```

i got that element name that i am using from the website i am trying to enter information into.  the code for the textfeild is

```
<input name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentMain$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucCreateEditCustomer$ucShippingAddressForm$tbFirstName"  
type="text"  
id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentMain_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucCreateEditCustomer_ucShippingAddressForm_tbFirstName"  
class="AddressFormTextBox" />
```

does anyone know why i might be getting this error?  Jwebunit easly connects to google and this website but it cant fillout any of the textboxes.  any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that:

> name="(..)$ucCreateEditCustomer$uc**Shipping**AddressForm$tbFirstName"
>
> (...)$ucCreateEditCustomer$uc**Billing**AddressForm$tbFirstName"

may be the cause of the issue.

Comment: Sorry the webpage has 2 boxes one with $ucShipping and one with $ucBilling besides that their name is the same and they both can't be found  but thanks for catching that mistake

Comment: so i just noticed something the "$" means it is a php variable. does anyone know how to get the value of a php variable using JWebUnit or a similar java library?